# Groovy - Jira OAuth integration using HttpBuilder

Tags: groovy, oauth, jira-rest-api, httpbuilder

I want to get data using [JIRA REST api](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-oauth-authentication) with provided `JIRA OAuth authentication` service.

Basically I'm able to achieve this task using [`ScribeJava`](https://github.com/scribejava/scribejava/wiki/getting-started) with `Groovy`. But I want to decoupled all the process as below :-

- Request to get request token
- Request to get authorized URL
- Request to access token
- Request to get actual data using [`HTTPBuilder`](https://github.com/jgritman/httpbuilder)

So I'm able to achieve above mentioned first three steps using [`ScribeJava`](https://github.com/scribejava/scribejava/wiki/getting-started) and storing the `accessToken` into `Database` for further request for data as below :-

```
import java.security.KeyFactory
import java.security.PrivateKey
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec

import com.github.scribejava.core.builder.api.DefaultApi10a
import com.github.scribejava.core.model.OAuth1RequestToken
import com.github.scribejava.core.services.RSASha1SignatureService
import com.github.scribejava.core.services.SignatureService


class JiraOauthProvider extends DefaultApi10a {

    private String authURL
    private String requestTokenURL
    private String accessTokenURL
    private String consumerPrivateKey

    private JiraOauthProvider(authURL, requestTokenURL, accessTokenURL, consumerPrivateKey) {
        this.authURL = authURL
        this.requestTokenURL = requestTokenURL
        this.accessTokenURL = accessTokenURL
        this.consumerPrivateKey = consumerPrivateKey
    }

    private static JiraOauthProvider instance = null

    public static JiraOauthProvider instance(Map map) {
        if(instance == null) {
            instance = new JiraOauthProvider(map.authURL,
                    map.requestTokenURL,
                    map.accessTokenURL,
                    map.consumerPrivateKey)
        }
        return instance
    }

    @Override
    public String getAccessTokenEndpoint() {
        return accessTokenURL
    }

    @Override
    public String getRequestTokenEndpoint() {
        return requestTokenURL
    }

    @Override
    public String getAuthorizationUrl(OAuth1RequestToken requestToken) {
        return String.format(authURL, requestToken.getToken())
    }

    @Override
    public SignatureService getSignatureService() {
        return new RSASha1SignatureService(getPrivateKey())
    }

    private PrivateKey getPrivateKey() {
        byte[] key = Base64.getDecoder().decode(consumerPrivateKey)
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(key)
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA")
        return kf.generatePrivate(keySpec)
    }
```

Now I'm building `OAuthService` as :-

```
private static final String CALLBACK_URI = "callback-url"
protected static final String CONSUMER_KEY = "consumer-key"
protected static final String CONSUMER_PRIVATE_KEY = "private-key"

Map oAuthMap = [
                "authURL" :"auth-url=%s",
                "requestTokenURL":"request-token-url",
                "accessTokenURL":"access-token-url",
                "consumerPrivateKey":CONSUMER_PRIVATE_KEY
            ]

//Buid oauth service to get request token, auth url and access token
OAuth10aService service = ServiceBuilder()
                .apiKey(CONSUMER_KEY)
                .apiSecret(CONSUMER_PRIVATE_KEY).callback(CALLBACK_URI)
                .build(JiraOauthProvider.instance(oAuthMap))

OAuth1RequestToken requestToken = service.getRequestToken()
def authURL = service.getAuthorizationUrl(requestToken)

//Now after redirect to this authURL and providing credential I'm getting oauthVerifier code to get accessToken and secretToken

def oauthVerifier = "oauth verifier code"

//Now calling to get accessToken
OAuth1AccessToken oAuth1AccessToken = service.getAccessToken(requestToken, oauthVerifier);
def accessToken = oAuth1AccessToken.getToken()
def secretToken = oAuth1AccessToken.getTokenSecret()
//now I'm storing this `accessToken`and `secretToken` into DB for further future data request.
```

So after all above stuff I'm able to achieve above mentioned three steps and storing the access token into `db` for future request only for `data`.

So to achieve 4th step to getting actual data using [`HTTPBuilder`](https://github.com/jgritman/httpbuilder) I'm doing some thing as below :-

```
def http  = new HTTPBuilder('base-url')

http.auth.oauth CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_PRIVATE_KEY, accessToken, secretToken

http.request(Method.GET, ContentType.JSON) { req ->
            uri.path = 'path'
            response.success = { resp, json ->
                println json
            }
            response.failure = { resp, json -> print json }
        }
    }
```

But I'm getting response as :-

```
{oauth_problem=signature_method_rejected}
```

So, could anyone suggest me how can I get actual data using [`HTTPBuilder`](https://github.com/jgritman/httpbuilder) with `OAuth` authentication using `accessToken` and secretToken?

**Note**:- I can get actual data as well using [`ScribeJava`](https://github.com/scribejava/scribejava/wiki/getting-started) Api with [`OAuthRequest`](https://github.com/scribejava/scribejava/blob/master/scribejava-core/src/main/java/com/github/scribejava/core/model/OAuthRequest.java) but requirement is to get actual data using [`HTTPBuilder`](https://github.com/jgritman/httpbuilder)

I just want a pointer that how to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lot of search I have got the solution [from here](https://gist.github.com/Thermionix/707e5755413fcbcb91b2). Actually [`HTTPBuilder`](https://github.com/jgritman/httpbuilder) internally using [`Signpost`](https://github.com/mttkay/signpost#signpost) which signing the request using [`HmacSha Signer`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4868) while `Jira rest api` supports `RSA-SHA1 Signer` to validate the `HttpRequest` that's why it's giving response as :-

```
{oauth_problem=signature_method_rejected}
```

So, basically I have to do custom `RSA-SHA1 Signer` to get the signature to http request. To achive this I'm using [`Google Data (GData) APIs`](https://github.com/google/gdata-java-client#description) to sign the data using `RSA-SHA1 Signer` before `HttprRequest` as below :-

```
private static PrivateKey getPrivateKey(String consumerKey) {
    try {
        byte[] key = Base64.getDecoder().decode(consumerKey)
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(key)
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA")
        return kf.generatePrivate(keySpec)
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e)
    }
}

import com.google.gdata.client.authn.oauth.OAuthParameters
import com.google.gdata.client.authn.oauth.OAuthRsaSha1Signer
import com.google.gdata.client.authn.oauth.OAuthUtil
import com.google.gdata.client.authn.oauth.RsaSha1PrivateKeyHelper

OAuthRsaSha1Signer rsaSigner = new OAuthRsaSha1Signer()
rsaSigner.setPrivateKey(getPrivateKey(CONSUMER_PRIVATE_KEY))

OAuthParameters params = new OAuthParameters()
params.setOAuthConsumerKey(CONSUMER_KEY)
params.setOAuthNonce(OAuthUtil.getNonce())
params.setOAuthTimestamp(OAuthUtil.getTimestamp())
params.setOAuthSignatureMethod("RSA-SHA1")
params.setOAuthType(OAuthParameters.OAuthType.TWO_LEGGED_OAUTH)
params.setOAuthToken(accessToken)

String paramString = params.getBaseParameters().sort().collect{it}.join('&')

String baseString = [
        OAuthUtil.encode("GET"),
        OAuthUtil.encode('base-url' + 'path'),
        OAuthUtil.encode(paramString)
    ].join('&')

String signature = rsaSigner.getSignature(baseString, params);

params.addCustomBaseParameter("oauth_signature", signature);

//Now calling using HTTPBuilder with signed data
def http = new HTTPBuilder('base-url')

http.request(Method.GET, ContentType.JSON) { req ->
        uri.path = 'path'
        uri.query = params.getBaseParameters()
        response.success = { resp, json ->
            println json
        }
        response.failure = { resp, json -> print json }
    }
}
```